# Why doesn't round work in this dplyr pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding

This is one of those annoying things that is a trivial problem to fix with an extra line of code, but I don't understand why my attempt to code as is doesn't work.

I am trying to round results in a dplyr pipe, but round doesn't work at the end and I am not sure why (but I suspect the division step is the issue).

Here is a reproducible example of the issue:

```
library(dplyr)

    # Use iris data set for reproducible example

    iris %>% 
      select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
      colSums() / 6 %>% 
      round()
```

Output:

```
Sepal.Length 
    146.0833
```

I was expecting the output to be 146, like when I do this (same thing, but storing the intermediate calculation in a variable "test":

```
test <- iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  colSums() / 6 

round(test)
```

Output:

```
Sepal.Length 
         146
```

round doesn't work in the dplyr pipe, whether I code it as `round(.,0)` or whether I have it as above.

It seems like the `/ 6` breaks the dplyr chain, but I would love to understand why and how I would correctly write this all in a dplyr chain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is operator precedence. `%>%` has higher operator precedence than `/` hence `6 %>%  round()` get executed first before `colSums() / 6` .

The operator precedence is given on the page `?Syntax`.

```
:: :::  access variables in a namespace
$ @ component / slot extraction
[ [[    indexing
^   exponentiation (right to left)
- + unary minus and plus
:   sequence operator
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%) #This also includes pipes %>%
* / multiply, divide #division is after pipes
+ - (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
!   negation
& &&    and
| ||    or
~   as in formulae
-> ->>  rightwards assignment
<- <<-  assignment (right to left)
=   assignment (right to left)
?   help (unary and binary)
```

The solution as already suggested is to make it explicit that you want `colSums() / 6` to be executed first before  `%>%  round()`.

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  {colSums(.) / 6} %>%  
  round()

#Sepal.Length 
#         146
```

Answer (score 1):

If we wrap with `{}`, it works

```
iris %>% 
  select(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  {colSums(.) / 6} %>%
  round
#   Sepal.Length 
#     146
```

---

Or another option is

```
iris %>% 
   select(Sepal.Length) %>%
   colSums %>% 
   divide_by(6) %>%
   round
#Sepal.Length 
#         146
```

---

Or another way is

```
iris %>%
   select(Sepal.Length) %>%
   colSums() %>% 
   `/`(6) %>% 
   round
#Sepal.Length 
#         146
```

---

Or use `summarise`

```
iris %>% 
    summarise(Sepal.Length = round(sum(Sepal.Length)/6))
#  Sepal.Length
#1          146
```

---

The issue is related to operator precedence.  According to `?Syntax`

```
The following unary and binary operators are defined. They are listed in precedence groups, from highest to lowest.

:: :::  access variables in a namespace
$ @ component / slot extraction
[ [[    indexing
^   exponentiation (right to left)
- + unary minus and plus
:   sequence operator
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%)
* / multiply, divide
+ - (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
!   negation
& &&    and
| ||    or
~   as in formulae
-> ->>  rightwards assignment
<- <<-  assignment (right to left)
=   assignment (right to left)
?   help (unary and binary)
```

Comment: Why are those brackets needed Akrun?  I suspected it was something like that, but I tried parenthesis and it did not work